# ASP.NET website structure / flow

Tags: asp.net, webforms

ASP.NET, web form model.

Is there any sample code/site that demonstrate a couple samples for regular website patterns/ templates? Like if I want to use tab to switch between different pages, should I put the code in a single page or in different page, and treat each tab as a page.

Or if in a search page (just a single search bar and button), should I display my result panel in same page using dynamically enable the result panel, or just to another page?

I want to find a general design pattern/ template. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: The benefit/curse of webforms is that there are so many server controls (bundled controls, nevermind the 3rd party controls) that sometimes it's not clear when to use different controls. There are so many ways to solve a problem or design a page, it seems like there's "one good way". Suggest finding the patterns that make sense to you, and sit down with the team to discuss pros/cons of each approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would give this a read and consider what best fits your application and your programming style, no one size fits all with paterns.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252940.aspx

After you have a general idea, head over to google.com and look for the patterns that catch your eye for simple tutorials

Edit:
For the specific question about whether you should modularize your code.  The answer is almost always yes.  If you think there is a chance that the component will be used somewhere else then doing this a head of time can save you a lot of headache later.  This practice also makes maintaining a lot easier because it gives a clear scope of what could be causing a bug.  Instead of having to look threw an entire page of unrelated code for things changing state unexpectedly in the page life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answer will be helpful to you or not. Correct me if I am wrong.

You are specifying demonstration about web designing. It seems the functionality you want is clearly saying to choose from weather you want to use AJAX or not. I suggest why don't you use [jQuery Framework](http://jquery.com/) for all this functionality.